# NetBSD - how to display information about kernel memory in GDB?

Tags: gdb, netbsd

I'm debugging the NetBSD kernel with `gdb`, but I would like to be able to display information about the memory region an address is in. I'm mainly interested in finding out the permissions of a page of memory, along with the size of the region it is enclosed in (if the latter part of that question makes sense).

Does the kernel have a concept of memory regions in kernel space? i.e. a contiguous block of pages (virtual addresses) reserved for a specific purpose (which is kept track of somewhere)? Or is it down to each specific module to keep track of which blocks of memory belong to a logical group?

Here's an example of what I'm looking for:

```
(gdb) addressinfo 0xffffffff80e1000

                Start                End    Offset    Perm     Size
    0xffffffff80e0000  0xffffffff80e2000    0x1000    r--p     0x2000
```

I don't mind adding a hook to the kernel for a GDB script to output this information, if this functionality does not exist. At the minimum it would be useful to add a hook for GDB scripts to view the page permissions.